# Is there a way to perform validations/assertions within method chaining in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

Is there any way to perform validations/assertions as part of method chaining?

This is very useful for long queries where we want to stop execution early on if a certain condition is not met.

Some possible examples:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
})

(
    df
    .assert((pl.col('A') == 'X').any(), message="At least one element in A should be X")
    .filter(pl.col('A') == 'X')
)

(
    df
    .assert((pl.col('A') == 'X').sum() > 1, message="At least 2 elements in A should be X")
    .filter(pl.col('A') == 'X')
)

(
    df
    .lazy()
    .assert([
        pl.cond((pl.col('A') == 'X').sum() > 1).message("At least 2 elements in A should be X"),
        pl.cond((pl.col('A') == 'Y').sum() > 1).message("At least 2 elements in A should be Y"),
    ])
    .filter(pl.col('A') == 'X')
    .collect()
)
```

Comment: Hi @T.H Rice, I don’t believe there is an assert function in Polars however you can do the assert on the Python side. Example: filter for column A = X, then do an assert based on the height of the dataframe. Is there a reason why the assert on the Python side would not work / would not be ideal ?

Comment: Thanks @Luca, it's more of syntactic sugar for regular DataFrames since it breaks method chaining, but it doesn't seem like it's possible for LazyFrames. You would have to `.collect()` and `.lazy()` for each assert, which defeats the purpose of optimized query planning.

Comment: Understood. For Lazyframes, it would make sense that it's not possible because Polars does not know the result of a lazyframe until it's materialised with collect(). 

The solution might be to process the data in batches, so you can stop a calculation early if you need. The Polars API has a good example on reading CSV in batches (https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv_batched.html). Would this help you?

I wonder if there is a way to use collect(streaming) to also run in batches. This might be a good question for Polars on github

Comment: P.S. I was wrong, there are asserts functions in Polars. but not for what you want to do I believe: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/testing.html#asserts

Comment: final thought: the batch might not work in your case, because you need to know all the values of the A column to run your test. So if stopping early then the test would not make sense. Maybe looking into casting string to categoricals if you have values which are repeated several times